# Calling base constructor in c++ CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli

If I inherit from a base class and want to pass something from the constructor of the inherited class to the constructor of the base class, how do I do that?

For example,

If I inherit from the Exception class I want to do something like this:

in C# Language we do it like this:

```
public class CppDynamicSyntaxLanguage : DynamicOutliningSyntaxLanguage
{
  public CppDynamicSyntaxLanguage(string key, bool secure) :
   **base(key, secure)** {}
}
```

**but how to do it in c++.net ?**
i try to do it like this :

```
public ref class CppDynamicSyntaxLanguage : public DynamicOutliningSyntaxLanguage 
{
public:
 CppDynamicSyntaxLanguage (String ^key, bool secure) : 
  **CppDynamicSyntaxLanguage(key,secure)** {};
}
```

but i got
Error
'MyEditor::CppDynamicSyntaxLanguage' : illegal member initialization: 'CppDynamicSyntaxLanguage' is not a base or member

"Thank You"

Answer (score 8):

The base class is named `DynamicOutliningSyntaxLanguage`, not `CppDynamicSyntaxLanguage`.

```
CppDynamicSyntaxLanguage (String ^key, bool secure) 
    : DynamicOutliningSyntaxLanguage(key,secure) { };
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
class CppDynamicSyntaxLanguage: public DynamicOutliningSyntaxLanguage {
public:
    CppDynamicSyntaxLanguage(string key, bool secure):
        DynamicOutliningSyntaxLanguage(key, secure) {
    }
};
```

It would work in c++, don't know about .net. Assuming DynamicOutliningSyntaxLanguage has a constructor that consumes sting and bool.